# запуск uwsgi ini

Tags: uwsgi

Деплою проект на django, установил uwsgi, запускаю приложение таким образом:

```
uwsgi --socket uwsgi_nginx.sock --module prof1.wsgi --chmod-socket=666
```

Всё работает,но когда я пытаюсь запустить через ini файл, то ничего не работает, код ini:

```
#mysite_uwsgi.ini 
[uwsgi]

chdir           = /root/prof1
module          = prof1.wsgi
home            = /root/prof1/venv
master          = true
processes       = 10
socket          = /root/uwsgi_nginx.sock
chmod-socket    = 666
vacuum          = true
```

Пути 100 раз перепроверил, запускаю этот файл вот так:

```
uwsgi --ini prof1_uwsgi.ini
```

Выводится это (тоже самое, что при запуске без ini, но в первом случае работает, а тут нет):

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from prof1_uwsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18 (64bit) on [Wed Apr  8 15:45:13 2020] ***
compiled with version: 7.5.0 on 08 April 2020 12:21:34
os: Linux-4.15.0-72-generic #81-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 26 12:20:02 UTC 2019
nodename: 194-58-107-218.cloudvps.regruhosting.ru
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 2
current working directory: /root/prof1
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
chdir() to /root/prof1
your processes number limit is 3854
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /root/uwsgi_nginx.sock fd 3
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
Python version: 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02)  [GCC 8.3.0]
PEP 405 virtualenv detected: /root/prof1/venv
Set PythonHome to /root/prof1/venv
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x562c3f33add0
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 801944 bytes (783 KB) for 10 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x562c3f33add0 pid: 19375 (default app)
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 19375)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 19377, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 19378, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 19379, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 19380, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 5 (pid: 19381, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 6 (pid: 19382, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 7 (pid: 19383, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 8 (pid: 19384, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 9 (pid: 19385, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 10 (pid: 19386, cores: 1)
```

Если нужно больше кода - скину

Comment: «WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!!» — крайне рекомендую вам подумать о том, чтобы перестать запускать Django от имени root во имя безопасности.

Comment: @andreymal я это понимаю, это был тестовый запуск, для отладки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверял 10 раз пути, прям уверен был, что не ошибся, тогда я уставший был и уже ничего не понимал, сейчас нашёл банальную ошибку - неправильно указал путь к сокету